# Finding matching indicators for multiple countries, with data extracted with the OECD package in R

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, match

I'm trying to find the indicators that are **commonly** available for three countries with the package `OECD`. This is what I've been doing, but it is not working:

```
# AVAILABLE MONTHLY DATA - OECD

list.of.packages <- c("OECD", "dplyr")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)

library(OECD)
library(dplyr)

dataset <- "MEI" # MAIN ECONOMIC INDICATORS
dstruc <- get_data_structure(dataset)
list_MEI <- dstruc$SUBJECT
str(dstruc)
filter_list <- list(c("MEX", "BRA", "RUS"), "", "", "M") # SEQUENCE SENSITIVE
MEI_INDICATORS <- get_dataset(dataset = dataset, filter = filter_list)

MEI_INDICATORS_BRA <- subset(MEI_INDICATORS, LOCATION == "BRA") %>%
  select(LOCATION, SUBJECT, MEASURE)
MEI_INDICATORS_MEX <- subset(MEI_INDICATORS, LOCATION == "MEX") %>%
  select(LOCATION, SUBJECT, MEASURE)
MEI_INDICATORS_RUS <- subset(MEI_INDICATORS, LOCATION == "RUS") %>%
  select(LOCATION, SUBJECT, MEASURE)

MEI_INDICATORS_ALL <- merge(MEI_INDICATORS_BRA, MEI_INDICATORS_MEX, by = "SUBJECT")
MEI_INDICATORS_ALL <- merge(MEI_INDICATORS_ALL, MEI_INDICATORS_RUS, by = "SUBJECT")

MEI.AVAILABLE.4ALL <- merge(MEI_INDICATORS_ALL, list_MEI, by = "SUBJECT") %>%
  arrange(SUBJECT)
```

Could you please indicate a more efficient way to find the matches? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by @alex_jwb90, I am "looking for tuples of `SUBJECT` and `MEASURE` that appear in all three sets".

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more information about what you are having an issue with? That subset section could probably be skipped by using `filter` and `%in%` in `dplyr`.

Comment: I would like a ```unique``` sort of result, giving me the names of commonly available indicators (jointly ```SUBJECT``` and ```MEASURE```).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to filter the `MEI_INDICATORS` dataset you have prepared to include only those `SUBJECT` indicators that are available for all of Russia, Brazil and Mexico, is that it?

// UPDATE: as specified in the comments below, OP is looking for tuples of `SUBJECT` and `MEASURE` that appear in all three sets, not only `SUBJECT`.
CHanged answer to reflect that.

Try the following:

```
library(dplyr)

[...]

MEI.AVAILABLE.4ALL <- MEI_INDICATORS %>%
  group_by(SUBJECT, MEASURE) %>%
  filter(
    any(LOCATION == "BRA"),
    any(LOCATION == "MEX"),
    any(LOCATION == "RUS")
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(LOCATION, SUBJECT, MEASURE) %>%
  arrange(SUBJECT)
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to prepare the list of subjects that appear in the three disjunct local datasets, you can use `intersect` (you'll have to nest it though), like this:

```
library(dplyr)

[...]

common_subjectXmeasure <- MEI_INDICATORS_BRA %>%
  select(SUBJECT, MEASURE) %>%
  intersect( MEI_INDICATORS_MEX %>% select(SUBJECT, MEASURE) ) %>%
  intersect( MEI_INDICATORS_RUS %>% select(SUBJECT, MEASURE) ) %>%
  distinct()

MEI.AVAILABLE.4ALL <- common_subjectXmeasure %>%
  left_join(MEI_INDICATORS, by = c('SUBJECT', 'MEASURE')) %>%
  select(LOCATION, SUBJECT, MEASURE) %>%
  arrange(SUBJECT)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm looking for subjects that are simultaneously present for all three countries. Your answer still keeps subjects that are not available for all of them: e.g. LOCOBPOR (```SUBJECT```), with STSA in ```MEASURE```, is showing for Brazil and Mexico. It's not present for Russia, so it shouldn't be there. Thanks!

Comment: oooh, so the combination of `SUBJECT` and `MEASURE` is expected to be available on all three locations? you're absolutely right, my solution was only looking at `SUBJECT`. in that case, just group by both of those variables simultaneously (`group_by(SUBJECT, MEASURE)`) and you'll be good to go with the first code-block :) - the second suggestion, however, won't work as easily for you then.

Comment: I've updated my code in the above answer to reflect this. please also try to update your original question to give a little more clarity about what you are looking for :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @alex_jw90! Sorry for the lack of clarity. I am adding an update to the question using your very helpful answer.

Comment: ```MEI.AVAILABLE.4ALL <- MEI_INDICATORS %>%
  group_by(SUBJECT, MEASURE) %>%
  filter(
    any(LOCATION == "BRA"),
    any(LOCATION == "MEX"),
    any(LOCATION == "RUS")
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(LOCATION, SUBJECT, MEASURE) %>%
  arrange(SUBJECT) %>%
  unique()

list_MEI <- dstruc$SUBJECT
colnames(list_MEI) <- c("SUBJECT", "LABEL")

MEI.AVAILABLE.4ALL <- merge(MEI.AVAILABLE.4ALL, list_MEI, by = "SUBJECT") %>%
  select(-LOCATION) %>%
  unique() %>%
  arrange(LABEL)```

Comment: could you please update your answer (the first part) with the code in my previous comment? This is exactly what I am looking for. Finally, there are 111 indicators available for Brazil, Mexico and Russia. Thanks in advance!

Comment: actually, since this isn't anything that will help others to solve the problem you have described, I'd prefer to keep it here in the comments for your personal reference

Comment: Just check the last line of code in the question. I was looking for a merge with ```list_MEI```. It's described there

Answer (score 0):

Based on @alex_jwb90 answer, this is the full answer:

```
# AVAILABLE MONTHLY DATA - OECD

list.of.packages <- c("OECD", "dplyr")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)

library(OECD)
library(dplyr)

dataset <- "MEI" # MAIN ECONOMIC INDICATORS
dstruc <- get_data_structure(dataset)
list_MEI <- dstruc$SUBJECT
str(dstruc)
filter_list <- list(c("MEX", "BRA", "RUS"), "", "", "M") # SEQUENCE SENSITIVE
MEI_INDICATORS <- get_dataset(dataset = dataset, filter = filter_list)

MEI.AVAILABLE.4ALL <- MEI_INDICATORS %>%
  group_by(SUBJECT, MEASURE) %>%
  filter(
    any(LOCATION == "BRA"),
    any(LOCATION == "MEX"),
    any(LOCATION == "RUS")
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(LOCATION, SUBJECT, MEASURE) %>%
  arrange(SUBJECT) %>%
  unique()

colnames(list_MEI) <- c("SUBJECT", "LABEL")

MEI.AVAILABLE.4ALL <- merge(MEI.AVAILABLE.4ALL, list_MEI, by = "SUBJECT") %>%
  select(-LOCATION) %>%
  unique() %>%
  arrange(LABEL)
```

Finally, there are 111 indicators containing data for Brazil, Mexico, and Russia (common indicators).